# xmlrpc multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, xml-rpc

Breaking my head ;-)
I'm using xmlrpc for php..

I got the instructions to send this request to the server:

```
'lines':[{'product_cod':'ZOIX333','qty':1.0,'price_unit':366.00,'discount_pct':0.0,'taxes':33.00,'tax_included':True}], #{...},{},{}]
```

So I tried:

```
            $order_line_items = array(
            array(
                'product_cod'   =>      new xmlrpcval('ZWWX4135', "string") , 
                'qty'           =>      new xmlrpcval('1.0', "string") , 
                'price_unit'    =>      new xmlrpcval('166.00', "string") , 
                'discount_pct'  =>      new xmlrpcval('0.0', "string") , 
                'taxes'         =>      new xmlrpcval('16.44', "string") ,
                'tax_included'  =>      new xmlrpcval('true', "string")
            ),
            array(
                'product_cod'   =>      new xmlrpcval('ZWWX4136', "string") , 
                'qty'           =>      new xmlrpcval('1.0', "string") , 
                'price_unit'    =>      new xmlrpcval('176.00', "string") , 
                'discount_pct'  =>      new xmlrpcval('0.0', "string") , 
                'taxes'         =>      new xmlrpcval('17.44', "string") ,
                'tax_included'  =>      new xmlrpcval('true', "string")
            )
        );
```

And then added it to the xmlrpc request with:

```
'lines'             =>          new xmlrpcval($order_line_items, "struct") ,
```

This genereates an error: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function serialize() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/sitename.com/httpdocs/openerp/xmlrpc.inc on line 3006

Passing a single item array works however.

So I'm lost how to create an array for multiple products and convert that..

Any help highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Bas

Answer (score 1):

This's answer althought late:

```
 $order_line_items[] = new xmlrpcval(array(

                'product_cod'   =>      new xmlrpcval('ZWWX4135', "string") , 
                'qty'           =>      new xmlrpcval('1.0', "string") , 
                'price_unit'    =>      new xmlrpcval('166.00', "string") , 
                'discount_pct'  =>      new xmlrpcval('0.0', "string") , 
                'taxes'         =>      new xmlrpcval('16.44', "string") ,
                'tax_included'  =>      new xmlrpcval('true', "string")
            ),'struct');



$order_line_items[] = new xmlrpcval(array(
                'product_cod'   =>      new xmlrpcval('ZWWX4136', "string") , 
                'qty'           =>      new xmlrpcval('1.0', "string") , 
                'price_unit'    =>      new xmlrpcval('176.00', "string") , 
                'discount_pct'  =>      new xmlrpcval('0.0', "string") , 
                'taxes'         =>      new xmlrpcval('17.44', "string") ,
                'tax_included'  =>      new xmlrpcval('true', "string")
            ),'struct');

'lines'             =>          new xmlrpcval($order_line_items, "array")
```

Hope it will help you